# CCArray VS ccArray

Tags: cocos2d-x

[image]

What is difference between `CCArray` and `ccArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCArray is class to used manage memory and the ccArray is the actual object.

more information available in this link   http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/CCArray

best of luck...

Answer (score 0):

`ccArray` is the actual struct object that is used, and `CCArray` is a class that is used to manage the memory of it so that you don't have to.